# Get list of source files (and locations) from binary

Tags: c++, binary, gdb, objdump

I'm working in a linux distro. I'm writing a C/C++ program that requires a list of source files that a binary (executable) was compiled with. I compiled the binary using GCC with the -g flag, of course. Using **gdb** I found out the format of the binary is DWARF2:

```
(gdb) info source
Current source file is src/main.cpp
Compilation directory is /path/to/source
Located in /path/to/source/src/main.cpp 
Contains 43 lines.
Source language is c++.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
```

Using **objdump** or **elfread** I see the information that I need:

```
bash> objdump -W binary
...
The File Name Table:
  Entry Dir Time    Size    Name
  1 1   0   0   main.cpp
  2 2   0   0   curses.h
  3 3   0   0   tprint.h
  4 3   0   0   twindow.h
  5 4   0   0   locale.h
...
```

Using **dwarfdump** I see that the variables of interest are: **DW_AT_comp_dir** and **DW_AT_decl_file**. Using a simple bash script (a few *grep* and *sed* calls) I was able to get the source list. What I would like to do, is get this source list from within a C/C++ program. For this purpose I have installed **libdwarf**, but with lack of any usage examples I'm unable to easily implement what I want.

My questions are:
1) Could someone provide a C/C++ example that reads debug information from a binary? It does not have to be with libdwarf if there are other libraries that can do this.
2) Can gdb provide a source list? Eventually I would like to build my own interface to gdb and scroll though available source files.

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can gdb provide a source list?

Yes: `info sources`

Comment: Thank you! I must have looked over that in the man pages. Still, a good example of a debug symbol reading library would be much appreciated.